# Can I have my sources in bitbucket for my Azure Devops project?

Tags: azure-devops, bitbucket

I thought I created a connection between my Azure Devops project and my sources in bitbucket but it looks like I imported it, so only a one time import.

Is it possible to just have my sources in bitbucket?

Comment: Please do independent research and read documentation before asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, I didn't find it. It would be foolish to find the answer and then still ask this question....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done actually is [importing an existing Git repo from Bitbucket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops) into a new or empty existing repo in your project in Azure DevOps.

`Is it possible to just have my sources in bitbucket?`

Only for CI/CD your could.

- Azure DevOps pipeline **support Bitbucket cloud when choosing source 
  in pipeline.**
- If your repo is on premise bitbucket server, please choose “other
  git” , then create a generic Git service connection , enter the URL
  and credentials.

  1. Firstly, check if you can access the BitBucket on-premise
     repositories with the external internet. If so, then the Hosted
     agents can also access them.
  2. Otherwise, deploying a private agent (self-hosted agent) on the
     BitBucket on-perm server or any other machine which located in the
     same network with the BitBucket on-perm server. Thus the private
     agent can access the BitBucket repositories.

***Note:*** Currently, Azure Pipelines only integrates with Git repos from Bitbucket. Mercurial repos in Bitbucket were not being shown.

In my opinion: Most online repos accomplish the same basic things: allow you to store code, collaborate with others, and make your code universally accessible to other systems.

Unless BitBucket Repo bring some unique capabilities you wanted to take advantage of. Otherwise I would suggest you simply migrate the repo and manage it in Azure DevOps directly.

Comment: "Unless BitBucket Repo bring some unique capabilities you wanted to take advantage of. Otherwise I would suggest you simply migrate the repo and manage it in Azure DevOps directly." That is a good question. I think I just migrate all the sources to Azure Devops.

Answer (score 2):

No. And yes.

No, you can't use Azure DevOps repository management UI to work with a repo hosted in Bitbucket. You use Bitbucket to manage repos hosted in Bitbucket.

Yes, Azure DevOps integrates with Bitbucket for continuous integration/continuous delivery purposes.